# Merge python lists of different lengths

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, merge, list-comprehension

I am attempting to merge two python lists, where their values at a given index will form a list (element) in a new list.  For example:

`merge_lists([1,2,3,4], [1,5]) = [[1,1], [2,5], [3], [4]]`

I could iterate on this function to combine ever more lists.  What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

### Edit (part 2)

Upon testing the answer I had previously selected, I realized I had additional criteria and a more general problem.  I would also like to combine lists containing lists ***or*** values.  For example:

`merge_lists([[1,2],[1]] , [3,4]) = [[1,2,3], [1,4]]`

The answers currently provided generate lists of higher dimensions in cases like this.

Comment: I have updated the problem description - realized I didn't need sets, just lists :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to use `itertools.zip_longest` (in python 3):

```
from itertools import zip_longest    

[[x for x in t if x is not None] for t in zip_longest([1,2,3,4], [1,5])]
# [[1, 1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]
```

If you prefer sets:

```
[{x for x in t if x is not None} for t in zip_longest([1,2,3,4], [1,5])]
# [{1}, {2, 5}, {3}, {4}]
```

---

In python 2, use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest    

[[x for x in t if x is not None] for t in izip_longest([1,2,3,4], [1,5])]
#[[1, 1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]
```

---

*Update* to handle the slightly more complicated case:

```
def flatten(lst):

    result = []
    for s in lst:
        if isinstance(s, list):
            result.extend(s)
        else:
            result.append(s)

    return result
```

This handles the above two cases pretty well:

```
[flatten(x for x in t if x is not None) for t in izip_longest([1,2,3,4], [1,5])]
# [[1, 1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]

[flatten(x for x in t if x is not None) for t in izip_longest([[1,2],[1]] , [3,4])]
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

Note even though this works for the above two cases, but it can still break under deeper nested structure, since the case can get complicated very quickly. For a more general solution, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists).

Comment: Is `if x` too broad, e.g. `0` would be removed? Perhaps an explicit test against `None`?

Comment: Also, OP tagged this a Python 2.7, so it would be `izip_longest`. `zip_longest` is Python 3.x

Comment: This answer is seriously awesome! I just threw it into a function like: `def merge_lists(a, b):
    return [[x for x in t if x is not None] for t in izip_longest(a, b)]` . Thank you!!

Comment: I have updated the description outlining a more general problem - could this solution be easily modified?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> lst1, lst2 = [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5]
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [list(filter(None, x)) for x in izip_longest(lst1, lst2)]
[[1, 1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]
```

How it works: `izip_longest()` aggregates the elements from two lists, filling missing values with `None`s, which you then filter out with `filter()`.

Comment: izip_longest does not exist in Python 3

Comment: The question is tagged `python-2.7`. In python 3 use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to have your desired output using `zip()`:

```
 def merge(a, b):
     m = min(len(a), len(b))
     sub = []
     for k,v in zip(a,b):
         sub.append([k, v])
     return sub + list([k] for k in a[m:]) if len(a) > len(b) else sub + list([k] for k in b[m:])

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 5]
print(merge(a, b))
>>> [[1, 1], [2, 5], [3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using zip_longest and chain from itertools:

```
import itertools
[i for i in list(itertools.chain(*itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2, list3))) if i is not None]
```

or in 2 lines (more readable):

```
merged_list = list(itertools.chain(*itertools.zip_longest(a, b, c)))
merged_list = [i for i in merged_list if i is not None]
```